# Yarn errors when running (context: Setting up WunderGraph GraphQL instance)

Tags: yarnpkg

Context:
I am attempting to run the [demo from Wundergraph](https://wundergraph.com/docs/guides/getting_started/quickstart) on a work computer. When I get to installing Wundergraph with Yarn, it fails. The Wundergraph error is.

```
Internal Error: Error when performing the request
    at ClientRequest.<Anonymous> (C:Users\{user name here}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\corepack\dist\corepack.js :3927:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (noe:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

With the socket issue, I am guessing there is a proxy or some other security issue on the client computer. I have successfully run the following on a separate, personal computer:

```
yarn global add @wundergraph/wunderctl@latest
```

No variation of yarn commands work on the work, computer (fails with any of the following):

```
yarn
yarn global add @wundergraph/wunderctl@latest
```

To eliminate possibilities:

1. On my local machine, yarn will not properly add path to wunderctl, which means searcing out the .exe to get the samples installed. This is a minor oversight in the demo, as the demo now works.
2. Does not matter if the command prompt is run as me or as administrator. It fails either way.
3. Fails on VPN and off, so VPN not the issue.
4. I can get things installed with NPM, but that appears to successfully install the .js files from Wundergraph and not the .exe. I am thinking this might be a clue.
5. I am going to work with others who say they have it installed and see how they did it, but that won't happen until next week. As I am contract and they are employees, it could end up being additional restrictions.
6. As this does it with yarn, as well as yarn {install command here}, I am guessing it is some check yarn does every time, or permissions on the yarn files themselves.

I know this is a long shot, but hoping someone encountered this and has found a way down the Rabbit Hole and then back out of wonderland. My fear is having to go full manual, edit the sample files heavily to eradicate yarn (for npm, most likely), have to wait until Wundergraph goes open source and grab the bits, work strictly from command line, or all of the above.

I have done a lot of searching for an answer before coming here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another package, with exactly the same error call stack.

First I updated NodeJS to the latest stable version 16.13.1 (I had 14.16.0). After that yarn showed signs of life:

```
yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
```

But then it failed with

```
RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT {ip address}:443
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
at ClientRequest.origin.emit (node_modules\got\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

That ip address was indeed unreachable due to a routing problem, after I fixed that all went well.